Cryptsetup fails to provide mountable device after update
I have updated Ubuntu from LTS 22.04 (jammy) to LTS 24.04 (noble), which also came with an update of the cryptsetup tool from cryptsetup 2.4.3 to cryptsetup 2.7.0.
I have always successfully mounted my partition using two commands:
cryptsetup open --type plain /dev/sda1 data
mount /dev/mapper/data /data

Since the latest Ubuntu update, I am receiving the following warnings when running the cryptsetup command:
WARNING: Using default options for cipher (aes-xts-plain64, key size 256 bits) that could be incompatible with older versions.
WARNING: Using default options for hash (sha256) that could be incompatible with older versions.
For plain mode, always use options --cipher, --key-size and if no keyfile is used, then also --hash.

Further, mounting the resulting mapper device results in an error:
mount: /data: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/data, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

This leads me to believe that some of the mentioned default parameters have changed. I have tried a bunch of combinations, without luck. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Clarified my post about Ubuntu versions.

In case anyone runs into the same issue, I had to specify the ripemd160 hash.
cryptsetup open --type plain --cipher aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 --key-size 256 --hash ripemd160 /dev/sda1 data

